# Mind-swap movie in which a guy swaps bodies with his personal trainer, who then exercises while the guy relaxes in the trainer's body

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am looking for a movie I have seen maybe in 2000-2010. It is about mind swapping. People can swap minds easily with others.

There's a scene in the movie where a guy swaps with his personal trainer, who then works out on the treadmill so that the guy can relax in the other body.

They also go to the club in another body and drink, etc., so that their own body doesn't get hurt.

Comment: Your question has been marked as a duplicate. That does not mean that it is a bad question, merely that it is one where the same answer has been provided. You will still get points for upvotes, and people can comment on it, but no more answers may be submitted.

Answer (score 5):

Xchange (2001)? This plot point is covered by [TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/XChange):

> The Xchange Corporation has developed a way to safely transfer minds between two bodies. The technology is mainly employed by "corpies" to travel (in the case of Toffler's boss, to swap with his personal trainer, so the boss can work, while the trainer can exercise the boss's body).

Comment: Omg you saved my life! I was going crazy googling it :)

Comment: @Elin - If this answer is correct, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the grey check mark near the top-left corner of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.